# Why Can't I Use Images With CoreMLTools In Python 3?

Tags: python-3.8, coremltools, macos-big-sur

I have a program where I need to use coremltools to predict something with and images, but when I feed the image through it dosen't work.

My code is:

```
import coremltools
from PIL import Image

img=Image.open('/path/to/jpg/file.jpg')
model=coremltools.models.MLModel('/path/to/mlmodel/file.mlmodel')
model.predict({'d':img})
```

But then it returns:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/models/model.py", line 329, in predict
    return self.__proxy__.predict(data, useCPUOnly)
RuntimeError: {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Predicted feature named 'classLabel' was not output by pipeline";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just faced this and for me I was not accessing not passing the correct keyword. My call was

```
model.predict( {"img": img } )
```

But when I printed the model, I saw this section of

```
input {
  name: "image"
  shortDescription: "Input image to be classified"
  ....
}
```

When I changed to:

```
model.predict( {"image": img} )
```

everything worked. Not sure what else could trigger the error as it seemed generic and unhelpful so maybe it could be an error in your other parameters as well.